QGIS Draw line form nearest parcel midpoint side facade to point
I have the following two layers:
'PARCEL' with polygon geometry corresponding to parcels.
'POINTS' with point geometry corresponding to the segmentation of the 'WAYS' layer at a distance of hectometer.
I need an expression for 'PARCEL' layer for Geometry Generator to draw a line from the midpoint of the nearest facade side to each hectometer POINT.
I have made an approximation with the following function but it is not what I am looking for because I have to generate a new layer with the centroids of 'PARCEL', and I can't capture the center of the side closest to each point either:
shortest_line ( 
collect_geometries ( 
overlay_nearest ( 
'POINT', 
$geometry
 )
 ),
 $geometry
)


What I would like to get:


My polygon layer is named parcel and my point layer is named hectometer.
To create the points (black in my screenshot) on the polygon boundaries closest to the nearest hectometer, combine overlay_nearest with closest_point. Adjust the max distance.
with_variable(name:='nearest', value:=overlay_nearest(layer:='hectometer', expression:=$geometry, limit:=1, max_distance:=300)[0], expression:=closest_point(geometry1:=boundary($geometry), geometry2:=@nearest))

The query will for each polygon find the nearest hectometer point, and retrieve its geometry.
Then combine it with make_line to create the lines:
with_variable(name:='nearest', value:=overlay_nearest(layer:='hectometer', expression:=$geometry, limit:=1, max_distance:=300)[0], expression:=make_line(closest_point(geometry1:=boundary($geometry), geometry2:=@nearest), @nearest))



Genial. Works perfectly.
